# How display text in a cell if the value of the cell next to it is above, below, or equal to 50%

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have been searching for a formula that will allow me to do what should be a simple conditional format.

I have a list of students and beside each name is a column that calculates the grade in recent exams. If this grade is 50% or higher I would like the cell beside it to display "Pass", otherwise it should display "Fail" by default.

I just can't seem to find any information on how to do this.

I'm using Excel 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest solution:

```
=IF(A1 >= 50, "Pass", "Fail")
```